# How to count the number of variants in SQL in the same column

Tags: sql

| product name | price | model_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone 11 | 600 | 1234576854,48503843246,23486759403,56482049586 |
| iPhone 11pro | 600 | 1234576854,48503843246,23486759403,56482049586,47586940382 |

Column `model_id` is showing the number of models in each product for example iPhone 11 has 4 variants while iPhone 11 Pro has 5.

I want to see how many variants for each product and the average of column `mode_id`.

The output should look something like this:

| product name | price | model_id | number of vibrant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone 11 | 600 | 1234576854,48503843246,23486759403,56482049586 | 4 |
| iPhone 11pro | 600 | 1234576854,48503843246,23486759403,56482049586,47586940382 | 5 |

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column to begin with. Do you have a chance to fix your data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a replacement trick here:

```sql
SELECT
    product_name,
    price,
    model_id,
    LENGTH(model_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(model_id, ',', '')) + 1 AS "number of vibrant"
FROM yourTable;
```

But regarding your current table design, in particular the `model_id` column, it is generally best to avoid storing unnormalized CSV data in your tables.  Do some research about database normalization to learn more about good database design.

Comment: and how to get the average of the whole column ?

Comment: You should edit your question and reveal the output you really want.  I have answered your question as you originally asked it above.

Comment: If you want to see the average of number of variants across the entire table, then use: `AVG(LENGTH(model_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(model_id, ',', '')) + 1) OVER ()` ... but this would mean adding a _new_ column with this value, and every row in the output would have this value.